# CSS animation is lagging and skipping, How to keep it uniform with text?

Tags: html, css, animation

On a site that I am building/testing stuff out on, there is this "caret" after my name that when initially loading goes slightly past the ending and then returns. Its hard to explain so here is an example. Watch the purple blinking caret.

https://codepen.io/Andrewbel1/project/editor/AwWOQq

```
 .typewriter h1 {
 // font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #747fe0;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', serif;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-right: 0.53em solid white;
 white-space: nowrap;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
 animation: typing 1.7s steps(35, end), blink-caret 
 1s step-end infinite;
}
```

So how could I get that blinking caret/rectangle to stick with the text and not go past and return right away?

I realize this a really specific question that probably no one else has but I really am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I got your issue and its cleared in below example see

```js
function toggleDarkLight() {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");
  var currentClass = body.className;
  body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f4f7ff;
  padding-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
body.dark-mode {
  background-color: #313438;
  color: #eee;
}
body.dark-mode a {
  color: #313438;
}
body.dark-mode button {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #313438;
}
body.light-mode {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #313438;
}
body.light-mode a {
  color: #313438;
}
body.light-mode button {
  background-color: #313438;
  color: #eee;
}

.container {
  font-size: calc(15px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
  line-height: calc(1.9em + (1.6 - 1.5) * ((100vw - 300px)/(1600 - 500)));
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.typewriter h1 {
  // font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #747fe0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 0.53em solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  animation: typing 1.7s steps(35, end), blink-caret 1s step-end 2;
}
.container {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.about_me {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #747fe0;
  }
}
.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-container .navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 305px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.navbar-container .navbar a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5d7a;
}
.hvr-float-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.hvr-float-shadow:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.hvr-float-shadow:hover, .hvr-float-shadow:focus, .hvr-float-shadow:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.hvr-float-shadow:hover:before, .hvr-float-shadow:focus:before, .hvr-float-shadow:active:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
.about_me {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 20px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.about_me a {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: #747fe0;
}
.parent {
  font-size: calc(19px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
  line-height: calc(1.9em + (1.6 - 1.5) * ((100vw - 300px)/(1600 - 500)));
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.backcolor {
  background-color: #708090;
}
.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.backcolor_child {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 8px;
}
.dot-1 {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.dot-2 {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.dot-3 {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.terminal_content {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  line-height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
.contactInfo {
  display: inline;
}
span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Andrew Belogurov</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Portfolio for Andrew Belogurov showcasing projects and skills.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Andrew Belogurov, Portfolio, About, Projects, Experience, Contact, Info, Information">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <body id="body" class="dark-mode">
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="arrow1 hvr-float-shadow">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <span>Google</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow2 hvr-float-shadow">
        <a href="https://www.example_not_re.com" target="_blank">
          <span>My Website</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow3 hvr-float-shadow">
<button type="button" name="dark_light" onclick="toggleDarkLight()" title="Toggle dark/light mode"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></button>
</div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="typewriter">
      <h1>&#62; Hi, I'm Andrew</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="about_me">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.
      <br>Check out some of my <a href="#recent projects" style="text-decoration:none"><strong><font color="#747fe0">recent projects</font></strong></a> below.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parent backcolor">
    <div class="child backcolor_child">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="dot-1"></div>
        <div class="dot-2"></div>
        <div class="dot-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terminal_content">
      <p><font color="white">&#62; Andrew.currentLocation</font></p>
      <p><font color = "#e0c260">&#34;Harrisburg, PA&#34;</font></p>
    <br>
    <br>
      <p><font color="white">&#62; Andrew.contactInfo</font></p>
      <!-- <p><font color = "#e0c260"> -->
      <span>&#91;&#34;<a href="mailto: andrewbel@example.com" target='_blank' style="text-decoration:none"><font color = "#43bddb">andrewbel@example.com>&#34;,</span>
      <span>&#34;<a href="https://github.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"><font color = "#43bddb">github</font></a>&#34;,</span>
      <span>&#34;<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"><font color = "#43bddb">stackoverflow</a></font>&#34;&#93;</span>

      <p><font color="white">&#62; andrew.resume</p>
      <p>&#34;<font color="#43bddb"><a href="#resume"target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"><font color = "#43bddb">Resume</font></a></font>&#34;</p>
    <br>
    <br>
      <p><font color="white">&#62; Andrew.interests</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p>sitiiheg</p>
  <h1>hehgeuh</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Small changes is done in animation and border color you can see in below code:

```
.typewriter h1 {
  border-right: 0.53em solid transparent;
  animation: typing 1.7s steps(35, end), blink-caret 1s step-end 2;
}
```

Comment: The gigantic take-away from this for me was that I could use [steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function) to effectively lower the FPS of a CSS animation and drastically reduce lag in instances where I have 100+ active animations. God tier info I just didn't know about.